# How to run a console program that using JNI bridge which is packed in an Android APK package?

Tags: android, java-native-interface, c++builder, rad-studio

Follow-up to my previous question: [How to run a console program which is packed in an Android APK package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76021416/)

In my app written in C++Builder 11.2, I might have found a way to run a console program which is packed in the APK. The console program, written in NDK aarch64, is named `test_run`:

```
extern "C" JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
ExecuteCommand(JNIEnv *env,  jstring cmd) {
    const char *cmd_str = env->GetStringUTFChars(cmd, NULL);

    char* alist[] = {0};
    char mode[] = "0754"; // make it executable
    int i;
    i = strtol(mode, 0, 8);
    int errno;
    if (errno = chmod (cmd_str,i) < 0)
    {
        sprintf(buffer, "%s: error in chmod( %s) - %d (%s)\n",
            cmd_str, mode, errno, strerror(errno));
        ShowMessage(UnicodeString("chmod failed: ")+UnicodeString(buffer));
    }
    execvp(cmd_str, alist); // or FILE* fp = popen(...)

    std::string result = "some result return";
    return env->NewStringUTF(result.c_str());
}
```

In `Button1Click()`, I'm calling:

```
// copy "test_run" executable file from APK installation folder to Documents or Download folder
// then:
::ExecuteCommand(JAVA_ENV, ConvertToJstring(DocumentsFolder + "/test_run") );
```

Now, in `ExecuteCommand()` function, calling `chmod` fails:

> Operate permission not allowed

How do I call a console program from my APK package using JNI? Or, maybe there is another way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need LegacyPackaging. Which zip the `.so` in `.apk` and unzip it to `lib/xxx` so you can execute it directly. You can set it in module `build.gradle` file, like this:

```
packagingOptions {
    jniLibs {
        useLegacyPackaging true
    }
}
```

Android used to extract the .so to file system from .apk.You can enable this feature by set android:extractNativeLibs="true" to your application tag in AndroidManifest.xml(if you do not have build.gradle file).You can use the .so like a program. It is a regular way. Here is the sample:

```kotlin
val cmd = arrayListOf(
                File(context.applicationInfo.nativeLibraryDir, "xxx.so").absolutePath
        )
ProcessBuilder(cmd).start()
```

Comment: i am sure that RadStudio has no "build.gradle" included in project workspace, by the way, has Android makes some "special" folder that allow APP to running "third part" program like you said: lib/xxx folder. and .so is dynamic lib, for directly running .so file(actually executable file renamed) is the "tricky thing" or "regular way" ?

Comment: @DarkSpy Android used to extract the .so to file system from .apk.You can enable this feature by set android:extractNativeLibs="true" to your application tag in AndroidManifest.xml.You can use the .so like a program. It is a regular way. Here is the sample:     
`
val cmd = arrayListOf(
                File(context.applicationInfo.nativeLibraryDir, "xxx.so").absolutePath
        )
ProcessBuilder(cmd).start()
`

Comment: thanks, I'll try to find the way based your content for implementing to RadStudio. anyway, the .so file is need to "from aarch64 exe file rename to .so" and pack into APK, like "assets/internal" folder,  am I right ?

Comment: @DarkSpy Yes,you need to know how to pack the `.so` into `.apk` by RadStudio. We put it in path `module_root/libs/abi(arm64-v8a/armeabi-v7a/..)/` normaly. The `.so` file will allways be packed into `lib/abi/` when build apk.

Comment: yep, @welcomeworld, at the deloyment function in RadStudio i put the so into lib/armaebi-v7a but not extract it, i thought it was not "native" lib but "renamed" fake .so file. and AndroidManifest.xml can not add options manually, its like IDE re-write depends on the project settings I think. but anyway, still trying

Comment: try AndroidManifest.xml modified, but still no .so file extracted, trying again

Comment: @DarkSpy Please check  if the final output apk  has packed the `.so` file correctly and the AndroidManifest.xml setup correctly. apk file is a zip file so you can extract it like a normal zip file.After install apk success,you can not view `.so` file in file explorer directly.You can check it by code ,like this Java code example:   ```       File nativeDir = new File(getApplicationInfo().nativeLibraryDir);
        Log.e("SoTest", "nativeLibDir:"+nativeDir.getAbsolutePath());
        for (String soFile : nativeDir.list()) {
            Log.e("SoTest", soFile);
        }  ```

Comment: still trying, but still not extracted. has any differences between "arm-v7a" executable or "aarch64" executable which i packed ? UI program is 32bit, will aarch64 executable can not be runs ?
anyway, i still have some confusing about the folder, is /data/usr/my_project/lib/arm like default executable running folder ?

Comment: @DarkSpy Can you provide me with your APK? If you pack `.so` into the `.apk` correctly,it will be extracted to `/data/app/xxxx/xxx/ ` with `x` permission. Even though it is rename from a normal txt to `.so` .

Comment: as I searching the internet these days i found that its not able to running a console program like linux or windows did, the simular way is like you said, make the console program to .so file, but in this case, it's lost some meaning from a individual program become a .so dynamic library in some way.

Answer (score 0):

This line is wrong, it does not do what you think it does:

> ```cpp
> if (errno = chmod (cmd_str,i) < 0)
> ```

Due to [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), it is evaluated *as-if* you had written it like this:

```cpp
if (errno = (chmod (cmd_str,i) < 0))
```

ie, the return value of `chmod()` is first compared to `< 0`, and then that *boolean* result is assigned to `errno`.  So, if `chmod()` succeeds then you end up setting `errno` to `0`, but if `chmod()` fails then you end up setting `errno` to `1`, which is `EPERM`, hence the `Operate permission not allowed` error message.

You need to write that expression like this instead:

```cpp
if ((errno = chmod (cmd_str,i)) < 0)
```

Or, like this:

```cpp
errno = chmod (cmd_str,i);
if (errno < 0)
```

ie, the return value of `chmod()` is first assigned to `errno`, and then that value is compared to `< 0`.

That being said, you really should not be naming your local variable as `errno`, as there is already a [standard `errno` variable](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) which `chmod()` sets on failure.  Name your local variable something more unique instead, and then use the standard `errno` when formatting your error message.  In which case, you can just get rid of your local variable altogether, eg:

```cpp
if (chmod (cmd_str,i) < 0)
```

Also, after calling `env->GetStringUTFChars()`, you need to call `env->ReleaseStringUTFChars()` or else you will leak the memory.

And, you can replace `::sprintf()` with either [`UnicodeString::sprintf()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.UnicodeString.sprintf) or [`UnicodeString::Format()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.UnicodeString.Format) to simplify the formatting of your error message.

Try this:

```cpp
extern "C" JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
ExecuteCommand(JNIEnv *env,  jstring cmd) {
    const char *cmd_str = env->GetStringUTFChars(cmd, NULL);

    const char mode[] = "0754"; // make it executable
    int i = strtol(mode, NULL, 8);
    if (chmod (cmd_str, i) < 0)
    {
        UnicodeString msg = UnicodeString().sprintf(L"chmod failed: %hs: error in chmod(%hs) - %d (%hs)\n",
            cmd_str, mode, errno, strerror(errno));
        /* alternatively:
        UnicodeString msg = UnicodeString::Format(_D("chmod failed: %s: error in chmod(%s) - %d (%s)\n"),
            ARRAYOFCONST(( cmd_str, mode, errno, strerror(errno) )) );
        */
        ShowMessage(msg);
    }

    char* alist[] = {NULL};
    execvp(cmd_str, alist); // or FILE* fp = popen(...)

    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(cmd, cmd_str);

    std::string result = "some result return";
    return env->NewStringUTF(result.c_str());
}
```

---

On a side note, be aware that `env->GetStringUTFChars()` and `env->NewStringUTF()` both operate on Java's [**Modified** UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7921016/), not *standard* UTF-8. This is not an issue if your strings contain ASCII characters only, but you might run into problems if they contain non-ASCII characters. Android runs on top of Linux, and Linux filesystem paths use *standard* UTF-8.

So, you may need to convert between *Modified* UTF-8 and *standard* UTF-8 when making external calls.  Otherwise, consider operating on Java's native (and *standard*) UTF-16 encoding instead, using `env->(Get|Release)StringChars()` and `env->NewString()`, and converting between UTF-16 and *standard* UTF-8 when needed, using another library, or your own manual code.

Or, you can convert a `jstring` to *standard* UTF-8 using Java's own [`String.getBytes(Charset)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes(java.nio.charset.Charset))<sup>1</sup> or [`String.getBytes(CharsetName)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes(java.lang.String)) method. And create a new `jstring` from *standard* UTF-8 using Java's native [`String(byte[], Charset)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(byte%5B%5D,%20java.nio.charset.Charset))<sup>1</sup> or [`String(byte[], CharsetName)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(byte%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String)) constructors.

<sup>1</sup> Java's [`StandardCharsets.UTF_8`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html#UTF_8) is a [`Charset`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) object for *standard* UTF-8.