# How to run a console program that using JNI bridge which is packed in an Android APK?

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, c++builder, rad-studio

Follow-up to my previous question version 1: [How to run a console program which is packed in an Android APK package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76021416/)

and version 2: [How to run a console program that using JNI bridge which is packed in an Android APK package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76065586/)

the problem still not solved.

In my app written in C++Builder 11.2, I need to run a console program which is packed in the APK. The console program, written in NDK aarch64, is named `test_run`, from 2 questions the problem still not solved.

and I changed my mind using jclass in RadStudio it's build successfully but crached:

```
  // copying test_run to the path we can use
  // get JAVA_VM and JAVA_ENV first, then:

  jclass runtimeClass = JAVA_ENV->FindClass("java/lang/Runtime");
  jmethodID getRuntimeMethod = JAVA_ENV->GetStaticMethodID(runtimeClass, "getRuntime", "()Ljava/lang/Runtime;");
  jobject runtimeObject = JAVA_ENV->CallStaticObjectMethod(runtimeClass, getRuntimeMethod);
  jclass processClass = JAVA_ENV->FindClass("java/lang/Process");
  jmethodID execMethod = JAVA_ENV->GetMethodID(runtimeClass, "exec", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Process;");


  std::string cmd = "chmod a+x ";
  cmd += path.c_str();
  jstring chmodCmd = JAVA_ENV->NewStringUTF(cmd.c_str());
  jobject chmodProcess = JAVA_ENV->CallObjectMethod(runtimeObject, execMethod, chmodCmd);
  JAVA_ENV->CallVoidMethod(chmodProcess, JAVA_ENV->GetMethodID(processClass, "waitFor", "()I"));

  std::string testCmd = path.c_str();
  testCmd += " arguments";
  jstring testCmdString = JAVA_ENV->NewStringUTF(testCmd.c_str());
  jobject testProcess = JAVA_ENV->CallObjectMethod(runtimeObject, execMethod, testCmdString);

  jobject processInputStream = JAVA_ENV->CallObjectMethod(testProcess, JAVA_ENV->GetMethodID(processClass, "getInputStream", "()Ljava/io/InputStream;"));
  jclass inputStreamClass = JAVA_ENV->FindClass("java/io/InputStream");
  jmethodID readMethod = JAVA_ENV->GetMethodID(inputStreamClass, "read", "([B)I");
  jint readBytes = 1;
  jint bufferSize = 1024;
  jbyteArray buffer = JAVA_ENV->NewByteArray(bufferSize);
  std::string output;
  while (readBytes > 0) {
    readBytes = JAVA_ENV->CallIntMethod(processInputStream, readMethod, buffer);
    if (readBytes > 0) {
      jbyte* b = JAVA_ENV->GetByteArrayElements(buffer, NULL);
      output += std::string((char*)b, readBytes);
      JAVA_ENV->ReleaseByteArrayElements(buffer, b, JNI_ABORT);
    }
  }
  ShowMessage(output.c_str());

  JAVA_ENV->DeleteLocalRef(runtimeClass);
  JAVA_ENV->DeleteLocalRef(processClass);
  JAVA_ENV->DeleteLocalRef(runtimeObject);
  JAVA_ENV->DeleteLocalRef(testProcess);
  JAVA_ENV->DeleteLocalRef(processInputStream);
  JAVA_ENV->DeleteLocalRef(inputStreamClass);
  JAVA_ENV->DeleteLocalRef(buffer);
```

please help. thanks